# How to show images from my sql to this table? in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a pagination code in php ,i tried to show images post_images from my sql to this table in my code but nothing happen ,i tried `echo '<img src= images/$post_image />';`
,can you tell me please what i can do ?

my code :

```
<table height="200px" style="border:3px black solid;border-radius:5px" width="550px">
<tr>
<th colspan="2" height="40px" style="border-bottom:3px black solid">posts in this site</th>
</tr>
<?php
    $link=mysql_connect("localhost","username","pass");
        mysql_select_db("itstuff_paging",$link);
    $q="select count(*) \"total\"  from posts";
    $ros=mysql_query($q,$link) or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($ros);
    $total=$row['total'];
    $dis=4;
    $total_page=ceil($total/$dis);
    $page_cur=(isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:1;
    $k=($page_cur-1)*$dis;

    $q="select * from posts limit $k,$dis";
    $ros=mysql_query($q,$link);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ros))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="10px" style="border-bottom:1px #a1a1a1 solid">'.$row

['post_id'].'.';

echo '<br/>';
        echo '<td style="border-bottom:1px #a1a1a1 solid">'.$row['post_title']; 
echo '<br/>';
                echo  ($row['post_content']);
echo '<br/>';
               echo '<img src= images/$post_image />';

        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<br/>';
    if($page_cur>1)
    {
        echo '<a href="index.php?page='.($page_cur-1).'" 

style="cursor:pointer;color:green;" ><input style="cursor:pointer;background-

color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:120px;height:30px;color:white;font-

size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value=" Previous "></a>';
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<input style="background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-

radius:5px;width:120px;height:30px;color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" 

value=" Previous ">';
    }
    for($i=1;$i<$total_page;$i++)
    {
        if($page_cur==$i)
        {
            echo ' <input style="background-color:green;border:2px black 

solid;border-radius:5px;width:30px;height:30px;color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" 

type="button" value="'.$i.'"> ';
        }
        else
        {
        echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'"> <input style="cursor:pointer;background-

color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:30px;height:30px;color:white;font-

size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value="'.$i.'"> </a>';
        }
    }
    if($page_cur<$total_page)
    {
        echo '<a href="index.php?page='.($page_cur+1).'"><input 

style="cursor:pointer;background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-

radius:5px;width:90px;height:30px;color:white;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" 

value=" Next "></a>';
    }
    else
    {
     echo '<input style="background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-

radius:5px;width:90px;height:30px;color:black;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" 

value="   Next ">';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you store urls to images or images binaries in a db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never define `$post_image` before you use it, so you're generating `<img src="" />`. Perhaps you meant:

```
echo "<img src=images/{$row['post_image']} />";
```

instead?

Comment: thank you very much,the problem is solved , and you are right

Answer (score 0):

Your code is malformed. Please try:

```
echo '<img src="images/'.$post_image.'" />';
```